# How is the method of Lagrange multipliers used for multiple constraints of multiple variables?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, constrained-dynamics

> Let's say for example that I have two constraints $f(x,\dot{x},y,\dot{y})$ and $g(x,\dot{x},y,\dot{y})$ and a Lagrangian $L(x,\dot{x},y,\dot{y})$. **What are the Euler-Lagrange equations of the first kind that describe the equations of motion of the system using Lagrange multipliers?**

My attempt at the solution is below, could anyone comment if it (and in general the approach) is correct? May seem trivial but I am having trouble checking it. Specifically, is it correct that the boundary terms vanish when integrating by parts?

Consider first a single constraint $f(x,\dot{x},y,\dot{y}) = const$.

Since:
$$ \delta f = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \delta y + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{y}} \delta \dot{y} = 0 $$

Since this is zero, I can add it to the variation in the action with some Lagrange multiplier $\lambda(t)$:

$$\delta S =  \int \left ( \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} \delta x + \frac{\partial L }{\partial \dot{x}}\delta \dot{x} + \lambda (t) \left ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\delta x + \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} \delta \dot{x} \right ) \right ) dt + (\text{same integral in y}) = 0$$

And integrate by parts to get

$$ \delta S = \int \left ( \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L }{\partial \dot{x}} + \lambda (t) \left ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} \right ) \right ) \delta x dt =0 $$
(same for y).

So I would conclude that the EL equations in this case are:

$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L }{\partial \dot{x}} + \lambda (t) \left ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} \right ) = 0$$

(and for y)

Or in general for two constraints $f,g$:

$$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial L }{\partial \dot{x}} + \lambda (t) \left ( \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial f}{\partial \dot{x}} \right ) + \mu (t) \left ( \frac{\partial g}{\partial x} - \frac{d}{dt} \frac{\partial g}{\partial \dot{x}} \right ) = 0 $$

(and for y)

Sorry if this seems trivial, can't find it answered anywhere else if this is correct? Thanks

Comment: Why is this called off-topic but there's another question (http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137131/) in the queue right now asking about convergence of integrals which is not? I suspect it's because the converging integral question framed it as solving $\langle p |1/\hat{r}|p \rangle$ whereas this question got right to the heart of the issue. I think we should try to look past these cosmetic differences and at least be consistent.

Comment: Kurt, this would fit the mold of this site better if you put your attempted solution in the question itself and then ask a specific question about it. I think folks don't like how this is formatted because your "question" doesn't actually contain a question.

Comment: Thanks, I tried rewording the question to make it more precise. I read here [link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) that the best way to try to answer my own question would be to add a reference to my answer in the question, and to post the answer separately, so I followed that format

Comment: Answering your own question is fine, but normally you do that if you're trying to *share information* or if you figure out the answer after posting the question. The present case doesn't fall into either of those patterns. You should format this as a precise question, which you more or less already did, and then include your attempt in the question area. That way, someone can come along and post an answer saying either "Yep, you got it" or "No, it goes like this...".

Comment: Kurt, you could also hop into the meta and try to force people to explain why they put your question on hold. There's been some confusion around here about what should and shouldn't be considered on-topic, and some people are being way too quick to close questions. I hope you'll stick up for yourself as your question is as much physics as several others which show up here all the time and aren't closed.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I deleted my answer post, and moved my attempted solution into the question details. No sarcasm or bitterness intended, but I hope someone out there will attempt an answer rather than stressing about its format

Comment: I'm glad you fixed the format. Format matters. Having a consistent format allows potential answerers to digest your question more easily and produce more readily useful answers.

Comment: Absolutely agree, no argument there. Thanks for your help Daniel. Legitimately hoping that this will get off hold and someone will answer. Thanks!

Comment: Dear people who voted to hold this question: It shows effort to arrive at a solution and asks about a specific physics concept. Please un-hold it.

Comment: Note that [check my work](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093) type questions are actually considered off-topic here. This question needs to be formulated in a manner such that it is *not* asking us to confirm or do the work.

Comment: @KyleKanos: If OP removes the work he did and reformulates the question to ask "how do I solve this physics related math question...?" will that suffice?

Comment: @DanielSank: I would say no because then it would be a no-effort "do my homework for me" type problem, which is also off-topic. He'd have to ask why the boundary conditions are what they are (in which case, he'd have answered the calculus portion of the question).

Comment: @KyleKanos: Where's the effort in this (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137420/harmonic-oscillator-differential-equation-solution) or this (http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/137131/evaluate-langle-mathbfp-1-hatr-mathbfp-rangle)? I'm really having a hard time understanding how people here make these judgements.

Comment: @DanielSank: The first has 4 close-votes pending, the second is asking about the physical interpretation of a particular integral. Asking "how do I do this?" is very different than "what does this mean?"

Comment: @KyleKanos: Nowhere in that second question does the OP ask "what does this mean". The title is "Evaluate $\langle p|1/\hat{r}|p\rangle$" and the OP points out that it diverges and asks "So, is that just it?" There is zero mention of physical meaning whatsoever. I suspect it was *interpreted* it that way and if we're willing to interpret questions to give OP the benefit of the doubt we should do that everywhere.

Comment: I have to say that the rules concerning homework are becoming too strict on the stack sites. When I do finish my degree, I, personally, would like to have a site where I could help people who are simply learning. I believe check my work questions are appropriate to learning, which is ultimately the goal of any homework.

Comment: I would agree as well. I finally got around to trying to understand my confusion when I first posed the question - there's an endlessly nice explanation of the answer [here](http://www.lepp.cornell.edu/~pt267/files/teaching/P3318S13/Sec_05_nonholonomic.pdf), although as always there are still more questions than answers. Essentially, I had no concept of non-holonomic constraints, leading to the question of whether or not they can be used in Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: Not to single out Kyle's comment, but the point is that if I had reworded the question to e.g. focus on asking why the boundary conditions are what they are, this wouldn't allow for a complete answer about non-holonomic constraints. In this way its just too easy to change the meaning of the question and worse to prevent answers addressing the actual point of confusion