# Harmonic oscillator differential equation solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

My math book explains how to solve second order equations like :
$$\ddot{x} + \omega^2x = 0$$

but I end up with the general solution : 
$$A\cos(\omega t) + iB\sin(\omega t).$$

Now my physics book says the solution is 
$$\rho\cos(\omega t + \phi)$$

How can I get there ***from the general*** solution?

Comment: The last formula is just another *representation* of the general solution. To relate the two possibilities expand $\cos{(\omega t+\phi)}$ by the formula for the cosine of sum and then try to chose parameters $\rho,\phi$ such that the obtained expression coincides with your own solution.

Comment: Why is there an $i$ in front of the $\sin$ term?

Comment: @DanielSank You can choose B to be $-iC, C \in \mathbb{R}$ and you will have a real solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the sum rule for cosines, we find
$$ \rho \cos(\omega t + \phi) = \rho \cos(\phi) \cos(\omega t) - \rho \sin(\phi) sin(\omega t).$$
So we see that $\rho \cos(\omega t + \phi)$ is the same as $A\cos(\omega t) + iB\sin(\omega t)$ when 
$$ A = \rho \cos(\phi)$$
and 
$$B = i\rho \sin(\phi).$$

Comment: If $B$ is complex, it means the position could be complex too, right?

Comment: Yes, if $A$ and $B$ are arbitrary complex numbers, then the solution of the differential equation will be complex. So we must additionaly constrain $A$ and $B$ so that the solution is real. In practice, this reality of the solution is enforced by allowing arbitrary $A$ and $B$ and then taking the real part of the solution, which of course is real, but still satisfies the original differential equation.

Comment: Im sorry didnt quite get it. What did you mean by '..reality of the solution is enforced..'? We just assume that A and b have some values that will cause the output to be real?

Comment: Yes. You are trying to find the motion of the object, which must be real-valued, so your solution must give you real values. Any A or B that gives you complex values aren't true solutions.

Comment: That's a lot of assumptions behind that equation! xD thanks alot man